# Get value of previous row / specific column from a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I need, for each (x) row of a dataframe, to get the value stored in the previous row (x-1) and in a specific target column. The header of the target column is stored in a column (Target_col) of the x row.

```
               0     1     2  Target_col
Date                                    
2022-01-01  37.0  26.0   NaN           0
2022-01-02   NaN  41.0   0.0           1
2022-01-03   NaN  40.0  43.0           1
2022-01-04   NaN   NaN  23.0           2
```

For example, in the last row my Target_value is 43.0, which is stored in the column "2" of the previous row.
This is the expected output:

```
               0     1     2  Target_col  Target_value
Date                                                  
2022-01-01  37.0  26.0   NaN           0           NaN
2022-01-02   NaN  41.0   0.0           1          26.0
2022-01-03   NaN  40.0  43.0           1          41.0
2022-01-04   NaN   NaN  23.0           2          43.0
```

I was able to get what I want by duplicating the df:

```
df2 = df.shift(periods=1)
df['Target_value'] = df2.lookup(df.index, df['Target_col'])
```

but I guess there is a smarter way to do that. Furthermore, lookup is deprecated. Any ideas?

Please note that I reshaped my question and the example df to make everything clearer, so itprorh66's answer and my comments to his answer are are no longer relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach the problem a little differently as illustrated below:
given a base dataframe of the form:
df:

```
    date         a       b      c
0   2022-01-01  12.0    11.0    NaN
1   2022-01-02  10.0    11.0    NaN
2   2022-01-03  NaN     10.0    10.0
3   2022-01-04  NaN     11.0    9.0
4   2022-01-05  NaN      NaN    12.0
```

In stead of defining the column that contains the first valid data, I would create a column which just contains the first valid piece of data as follows:

```
# helper function to find first valid data
def findfirst(row, cols_list):
    # return the first non-Nan value found within row
    for c in cols_list:
        if not np.isnan(row[c]):
            return row[c]
    return np.nan
```

Then using the above helper, I add the column 'First' which contains the desired data as follows:

```
df['First'] = df.apply(lambda row: findfirst(row, ['a', 'b', 'c']), axis= 1)
```

This create the following dataframe:

```
    date          a       b      c      First
0   2022-01-01  12.0    11.0    NaN     12.0
1   2022-01-02  10.0    11.0    NaN     10.0
2   2022-01-03  NaN     10.0    10.0    10.0
3   2022-01-04  NaN     11.0    9.0     11.0
4   2022-01-05  NaN      NaN    12.0    12.0
```

From the above you can then compute the change value as follows:

```
df['Change'] = (df['First']/df['First'].shift())-1
```

Which yields:

```
**  date    a   b   c   First   Change
0   2022-01-01  12.0    11.0    NaN 12.0    NaN
1   2022-01-02  10.0    11.0    NaN 10.0    -0.166667
2   2022-01-03  NaN 10.0    10.0    10.0    0.000000
3   2022-01-04  NaN 11.0    9.0 11.0    0.100000
4   2022-01-05  NaN NaN 12.0    12.0    0.090909**
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not what I need. I don't need to compute the change of the current "First" vs previous day's "First", but current "First" vs itself. So, on 2022-01-03 it should be 10/11-1, and not 10/10-1

Comment: That is not what you show in your example nor is it what you said above when you state "need to find the percentage change (from the previous day) of the first non blank column."  Computing percent change from itself doesn't make sense

Comment: I'm not sure why you say that is not what my example shows: in my sample dataframe, the change on 2022-01-03 was -0.090909 and not 0 as in yours. Computing the change of the current "First" vs itself means comparing the current value of today's first with the previous value of ***today's*** (and not yesterday's) first

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the previous value of today?  Can you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: Sure: on 2022-01-03 the first not NaN column was "1". So, on 2022-01-03 change is 10 (the value of column 1 today) / 11 (the value of column 1 the day before) -1 = -0.090909

Comment: I reshaped the question and the sample df. I hope it's clearer now

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit convoluted but this works:

```
cols = df.columns[:-1]
temp = df['Target_col'].shift(-1).values[:-1]
temp = np.append(temp, 0)
target_values = df[cols].to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), temp.astype(int)][:-1]
target_values = np.insert(target_values, 0, 0, axis=0)
df['target_values'] = target_values.tolist()
```